# What is com.vm.common.view.fab?

Tags: android, button, action, floating

What is com.vm.common.view.fab? And what is it used for? Is it the Floating action button included with Android or is it another 3rd party one. I can't seem to find any good info on it.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

com.vm.common is a package name 
it's the inverse of a domain name common.vm.com

and yes fab refer to a floating action button included in android

Comment: Is it the same one that can be placed below a page header and scrolls up along with the page when scrolling? Or is that a different 3rd party one?

Comment: can you  show us where you've found this path to be more specific?

Comment: I found it in some older code. Any ideas how to import those libraries. I can't seem the find any info. Is it Eclipse, Android, Studio, etc...